# Creating line item of specific type programmatically

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to create a line item of specific type (different from the default "Product" type) programmatically? The function `commerce_product_line_item_new()`creates a line item of type Product. I can't find a function that let's you specify an existing line item type other than the default Product one.

EDIT: Never mind. I just realized that the `commerce_product_line_item_new()` function has a $type parameter that defaults to Product. Not sure how to delete the question, but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: This probably will help someone in the future - would you mind taking the resolution out of the question and putting it in an answer? Self-answering is encouraged here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just realized that the commerce_product_line_item_new() function has a $type parameter that defaults to Product. Not sure how to delete the question, but maybe it will help someone else.